# Find where a program aborts (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, abort

I have a huge VB6 legacy program that I just converted to VB.net.
The main forms display on the screen, and I successfully print a comment on the last executable line before entering the Windows Message Loop.

Then the program dies (all windows disappear) with no indication of what went wrong.

I have been unable to determine what code is executing when this program aborts, and would appreciate ideas.

I am running in Visual Studio 2008 Professional (since the code was just converted from VB6), using the debugger.

I have added a method call as the first line in every timer_Tick handler and every form_Activated handler.  I also do the same call in many major functions.  There is a Breakpoint set in the first line of the sub that I call... and it is not hit after the message loop starts.

I have attempted to look at all Windows messages, but am not familiar with the Spy++ tool, and am totally swamped with messages.  I know I can limit to a particular window, by my program opens MANY windows, and it could be a new one trying to open that causes the failure.

**If I don't get other solutions, I can further research using Spy++, but I'd really like to get OTHER suggestions on finding the location.**

Thanks.

Comment: Does the app start up using a Main Form or from Sub Main?

Comment: There is an `Err` object that you can access which contains information on the latest error that occured. Try to put it somewhere (maybe an UnLoad event or something similar).

Comment: Some things I would try - move to latest VS (2013 Express for Desktop), turn off timers for now to make debug stepping easier

Comment: The app starts from Public Sub Main().

Comment: When starting from Sub Main Apps do not just *entering the Windows Message Loop*, your app is supposed to start it.  It sounds very much like that is not happening or not correctly so. You might add that code.    Also, when more than one person comments on your post, you need to use @username if you want that person to be notified of your response.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Err object.  There was no error, so it didn't find one... but another good tool for my chest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code, this is a guess but it would match what you describe is happening. When an app starts from `Sub Main`, your code has to *start* the message pump - it is not something that happens automatically:

```
Public Sub Main()
     ...
    ' same as `Enable XP Visual Styles in App settings
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()

    ...
    ' last line
    Application.Run(New MainForm())
End Sub
```

If you want to use Visual Styles, they need to be enabled before any form or control is referenced.

The message pump is started via `Application.Run`.   If you simply show your starting form (and/or others), the app will terminate when `Sub Main` terminates because there is no app message pump.

Comment: What a relief!  Yes, that was the problem.  The original VB6 code had the message loop code started, obviously, but somehow it got removed in the automated conversion.  So it was not crashing at all, just finishing normally.  Good call.  Now it stays up, and I can proceed with the conversion cleanup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling all exceptions in the Visual Studio debugger.  From the DEBUG menu, select Exceptions and check all the boxes under Thrown.   (Later you can use Reset All to revert to default settings.)  This may expose many exceptions which are otherwise handled and you can ignore, but could also lead you to the root issue.

Comment: That didn't find my problem, but great to learn about that capability!  It is flagging many potential problems that I can try to clean up.